# Sobrescrever trecho de arquivo com php?

Tags: php

Não sei como explicar meu problema, então vou exemplificar:
Estou usando `PHP` e gostaria de manipular um arquivo .txt de n linhas.
Cada linha possui um tamanho padrão de 20 caracteres.

Por exemplo... os 8 primeiros caracteres se referem a uma data de envio (ddmmaaa), os 2 próximos ao estado origem (SP, RJ, ...), os outros 2 ao estado destino e os 8 últimos ao código do produto.

```
Linha 1: 01012014RJPA00001472
Linha 2: 03121997MGRS00192010
...
Linha n: 28092012AMAC00000071
```

O que eu gostaria de saber é como sobrescrever um desses termos (não toda a linha, nem todo o arquivo) e salvar o arquivo.

Tipo: Na linha 2 do arquivo eu quero mudar o estado origem de MG para MT sem alterar os outros dados do arquivo. Como se eu levasse o ponteiro até uma posição antes do 'MG' apertasse o insert do teclado e digitasse 'MT'.

Comment: se você quer trabalhar com dados dessa forma eu te aconselho a ver sobre xml http://www.w3schools.com/xml/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras... O que você pediu, acredito que seja basicamente isso:

```
<?php

// Tamanho padrão da sua linha
$linha_tamanho_default = 20;

// Array que define o inicio do valor na linha de acordo com o tipo de dado
$inicio = array(
    "DATA" => 0,
    "UF" => 8,
    "DESTINO" => 10,
    "CODIGO" => 12,
);

// Define o tamanho de cada item de acordo com o tipo de dado
$tamanho = array(
    "DATA" => 8,
    "UF" => 2,
    "DESTINO" => 2,
    "CODIGO" => 8,
);

// simulando o arquivo em uma string
// equivale a um arquivo txt com o conteudo do comentário abaixo:
/* 
01012014RJPA00001472
03121997MGRS00192010
28092012AMAC00000071
*/
$arquivo = "01012014RJPA00001472\n03121997MGRS00192010\n28092012AMAC00000071";


/***** Abaixo os parâmetros definem que a UF da 3ª linha será substituida por RJ */

// Define que TIPO de valor será substituido
$tipo = "UF";
// Define a linha que será alterada
$linha = 3;
// Define o NOVO valor
$valor = "RJ";

// Calcula a posição para a substituição
// usa $linha-1 (pois a contagem inicia em 0)
// usa $linha_tamanho_default+1 (pois inclui o \n)
// soma com o inicio do item que deseja substituir de acordo com a linha
$posicao = ($linha-1)*($linha_tamanho_default+1) + $inicio[$tipo];

// Retorna o arquivo   
$arquivo = substr_replace($arquivo, $valor, $posicao, $tamanho[$tipo] );

// Printa os resultados
echo $arquivo;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seria interessante se você usasse expressões regulares para isso.

Você disse que seu arquivo de texto é composto de linhas no seguinte formato:

- 20 caracteres cada
- os 10 primeiros caracteres são datas, irrelevantes para nossos propósitos
- os 2 caracteres seguintes são o UF, dado que queremos trabalhar
- os 8 caracteres seguintes também são irrelevantes

Sendo assim, a expressão regular básica para cada linha seria:

```
/^(?P<data>.*){10}(?P<uf>.*){2}(?P<etc>.*){8}$/
```

Para substituirmos esses dados, basta usarmos a função `preg_replace`:

```
$siglaABuscar = 'MT';
$novaSigla    = 'MG';
$arquivo      = file_get_contents('arquivo.txt');
$arquivo      = preg_replace("/^(?P<data>.*){10}(?P<uf>$siglaABuscar){2}(?P<etc>.*){8}$/g", "$1$novaSigla$3", $arquivo);
file_put_contents('arquivo.txt', $arquivo);
```

PS: eu escrevi o código de cabeça, pode ser que haja alguns ajustes a serem feitos.

Comment: Não testei o código, também nunca usei expressões regulares com PHP. Eu posso está enganado, mas acho que nesse código eu alteraria todos os 'MT' do arquivo para 'MG'. Eu queria alterar apenas aquele específico da segunda linha. Tipo eu usaria um fgets() para levar o ponteiro até essa posição e usaria um fputs(), ou alguma forma de sobrescrever, para escrever os 2 novos caracteres 'por cima' dos antigos.

Comment: @HiranFilho Acho que o que você pode fazer é usar a função `file`, que carrega o arquivo em um array no qual cada chave contém uma linha do arquivo. Então, você alteraria apenas a chave `1` (que corresponderia à segunda linha) usando os parâmetros de entrada `MT` (que corresponde à sigla a ser buscada) e `MG` (que corresponde à nova sigla).

Answer (score 0):

Seguem algumas dicas que podem ajudar

Os métodos fopen(), fread(), fgets(), fwrite(), fclose() são usados para que se acesse e altere arquivos do seu script php.
http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php

Outra opção é "puxar tudo para um array", fazer as alterações, e depois gravar novamente o arquivo. (se forem muitas verificações e alterações, pode ser uma boa opção)

```
$arrayDeLinhas = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Isso lhe dará um array com as linhas do arquivo, depois pode-se manejar as informações como desejar.

Aqui pode-se encontrar algum método que te ajude a manejar a string.
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.strings.php

Acredito que wordwrap e substr_replace devem lhe ajudar. 
Mas daqui pra frente é a organização do teu algoritmo, ai é com você!